# Get the last true condition of multiple True conditions that there are in a list

Tags: python, dataframe, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary is of the format.

```
{'id': 'XYZ_ALL_UNIQUE',
 'event_type': 'TYPE OF EVENT',
 'created_time': '2023-05-29T11:23:54.456170Z'
}
```

There are multiple events and for all those events we have a unique dictionary item in the list. For example, `ORDER_CREATED` event, `ORDER_DELIVERED` event and so on with their unique time stamps.

There is **only** one event which is called `ORDER_FULFILLED` event. I can find the timestamp of that event using the following code.

```
for item in list_of_dict:
    if (item['event_type'] == 'ORDER_FULFILLED'):
        fulfilled_time = item['created_time']
```

But there are multiple events of event_type `ORDER_CHANGED` with their timestamps. When I filter them using the code below, I get all those events.

```
for item in list_of_dict:
    if (item['event_type'] == 'ORDER_CHANGED'):
        changed_time = item['created_time']
```

I just need the last event of this type. For example, if this event occurs at multiple times in the list of dictionary, the code should only output the last occurence timestamp and ignore all other events of the same type.

I tried using `list.count(True)`, but this doesn't help me in the way I want. So my question if how do I get the last true condition of multiple True conditions are there in a list? How can I do it in Python?

Comment: "When I filter them using the code below, I get all those events". What do you mean? `changed_time` should be overwritten at each step of the loop thus keeping only the last value of `item['created_time']`. How does your code not achieve what you want?

Comment: Just iterate over your list in reverse then the first occurrence of 'ORDER_CHANGED' will be the one you're interested in. Having said that, your code will give the same result. The only difference being that you have to navigate over all dictionaries

Comment: I used the overriding statement outside of the conditions so that I only have the last value now. Thanks @Tranbi

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this

```
last_timestamp = None

for item in reversed(data_list):
if item['event_type'] == 'ORDER_CHANGED':
    last_timestamp = item['created_time']
    break

print(last_timestamp)
```

This would result in the following example:

```
# Example list of dictionaries

data_list = [
{"timestamp": "2023-05-30 12:00:00", "condition": False},
{"timestamp": "2023-05-30 13:00:00", "condition": True},
{"timestamp": "2023-05-30 14:00:00", "condition": False},
{"timestamp": "2023-05-30 15:00:00", "condition": True},
{"timestamp": "2023-05-30 16:00:00", "condition": True},
{"timestamp": "2023-05-30 17:00:00", "condition": False}
]

# Find the last occurrence of true condition and return the corresponding 
timestamp
last_timestamp = None

for item in reversed(data_list):
    if item["condition"]:
        last_timestamp = item["timestamp"]
        break

print(last_timestamp)

2023-05-30 16:00:00
```

Comment: The reversed method won't work because there are multiple conditions and I want the original order. I have found the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try reversing the loop and breaking the loop when you get the first value.

```
last_changed_time = None
for item in reversed(list_of_dict):
if item['event_type'] == 'ORDER_CHANGED':
    last_changed_time = item['created_time']
    break

print(last_changed_time)
```

Comment: The reversed method won't work because there are multiple conditions and I want the original order. I have found the solution. Thanks :)